# How to connect to a GATT server using Android BLE API?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have this function to call connect the application I am developing to another BLE enabled device:

```
public boolean connecttoDevice(int position) {
    currentDevice = devices.get(position);
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) _client
            .getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    if(currentDevice != null 
       && bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(currentDevice, BluetoothProfile.GATT) != BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED 
       && bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(currentDevice, BluetoothProfile.GATT) != BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING
    ){
        mBluetoothGatt = currentDevice.connectGatt(_client, false, mGattCallback);
        System.out.println(currentDevice.getName()+":"+currentDevice.getAddress());
        System.out.println(bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(currentDevice, BluetoothProfile.GATT));
    }
    else return false;
    return !(mBluetoothGatt == null);
}
```

`_client` is the activity that calling this method. I found that after calling the method the connection state of the device is not changed at all, and the callback is never invoked. I am just wondering where did it go wrong?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: What is the other BLE device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not bother, there is a bug in the API for now, if you are going to connect to a BT classic and BLE dual mode device, the connection will fail.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  e.g. a link to the bug report would be good.